# how do i convert the working hours to Boolean?

Tags: sql, time, oracle-sqldeveloper, boolean-logic, granularity

how do I convert the working hours 08:00:00-11:59:00;13:00:00-16:59:00; into 48 digit Boolean format like

```
 "000000000000000011111111001111111100000000000000"
```

where each digit refers to 30 min granularity using Oracle SQL Query?

Comment: what have you tried? what about daylight saving time? what about weekends?

Comment: Daylight saving -NA, Weekend - all Zeros(48)  the posted question is for weekdays.

Comment: hi please provided your data schema and mock data, starting and ending hours was stored as DATETIME or you have only string like ('08:00:00-11:59:00;13:00:00-16:59:00') ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are starting from a string which always has semicolon-separated pairs of from/to times, with a trailing semicolon after the last pair; and those times are always HH24:MI:SS with the seconds always zero as shown; then... you can split the string into multiple string pairs representing each from/to pair:

```
select regexp_substr('08:00:00-11:59:00;13:00:00-16:59:00;', '(.*?)(;|-|$)', 1, (2 * level - 1), null, 1),
  regexp_substr('08:00:00-11:59:00;13:00:00-16:59:00;', '(.*?)(;|-|$)', 1, 2 * level, null, 1)
from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('08:00:00-11:59:00;13:00:00-16:59:00;', ';')
```

```
REGEXP_S REGEXP_S
-------- --------
08:00:00 11:59:00
13:00:00 16:59:00
```

And you can generate all the half-hour blocks in a nominal day (picking one not subject to a DST switch):

```
select to_char(date '2000-01-01' + ((level - 1) / 48), 'HH24:MI":00"')
from dual
connect by level <= 48
```

```
TO_CHAR(
--------
00:00:00
00:30:00
01:00:00
01:30:00
02:00:00
...
23:00:00
23:30:00
```

And then join those together to see where there is an overlap, using string comparison (which is why the time format matters); using CTEs to provide the initial string for simplicity and then the results of the two previous queries:

```
with t1 (working_hours) as (
  select '08:00:00-11:59:00;13:00:00-16:59:00;' from dual
),
t2 (working_from, working_to) as (
  select regexp_substr(working_hours, '(.*?)(;|-|$)', 1, (2 * level - 1), null, 1),
    regexp_substr(working_hours, '(.*?)(;|-|$)', 1, 2 * level, null, 1)
  from t1
  connect by level <= regexp_count(working_hours, ';')
),
t3 (block_from) as (
  select to_char(date '2000-01-01' + ((level - 1) / 48), 'HH24:MI":00"')
  from dual
  connect by level <= 48
)
select block_from,
  case when t2.working_from is null then 0 else 1 end as flag
from t3
left join t2 on t2.working_from <= t3.block_from and t2.working_to >= t3.block_from
```

```
BLOCK_FROM  FLAG
----------  ----
00:00:00    0
00:30:00    0
...
07:30:00    0
08:00:00    1
08:30:00    1
...
11:00:00    1
11:30:00    1
12:00:00    0
12:30:00    0
13:00:00    1
13:30:00    1
...
16:00:00    1
16:30:00    1
17:00:00    0
...
23:00:00    0
23:30:00    0
```

And then finally aggregate those together into a single result string:

```
with t1 (working_hours) as (
  select '08:00:00-11:59:00;13:00:00-16:59:00;' from dual
),
t2 (working_from, working_to) as (
  select regexp_substr(working_hours, '(.*?)(;|-|$)', 1, (2 * level - 1), null, 1),
    regexp_substr(working_hours, '(.*?)(;|-|$)', 1, 2 * level, null, 1)
  from t1
  connect by level <= regexp_count(working_hours, ';')
),
t3 (block_from) as (
  select to_char(date '2000-01-01' + ((level - 1) / 48), 'HH24:MI":00"')
  from dual
  connect by level <= 48
)
select listagg(case when t2.working_from is null then 0 else 1 end)
  within group (order by t3.block_from) as result
from t3
left join t2 on t2.working_from <= t3.block_from and t2.working_to >= t3.block_from
```

```
RESULT
------------------------------------------------
000000000000000011111111001111111100000000000000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6b555b60591ae7701e128246599692b2)

If your initial string is actually coming from a table and you need this conversion for multiple rows at once then the connect-by split is a bit more complicated, and a recursive CTE might be more suitable for that part.

Just for fun, [here's an example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7825f8d210465978606e96d66c5ea172).